# Webpack import React only once

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React project build with `webpack`.
There are several customized components which require React.
For some reason, I need change a prototype function of React.
Is there a way to make `webpack` import React only once (not import in every component)?
Then, I just need change the prototype of React at one single place.

The issue is similar to [this one](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2134)